# Change the number of authors shown in Bibliography in APA style

Tags: ms-word, bibliography

In MS Word 2010 I added the following new source with 9 authors:

```
Pang BC, Kuralmani V, Joshi R, Hongli Y, Lee KK, Ang BT, Li J, Leong TY, Ng I.
Hybrid outcome prediction model for severe traumatic brain injury.
J Neurotrauma. 2007 Jan;24(1):136-46.
```

But when I create the Bibliography not all authors are shown, some of them are replaced by ... as shown below:

```
Pang, B. C., Kuralmani , V., Joshi, R., Hongli, Y., Lee , K. K., Ang, B. T., . . . Ng, I. (2007). Hybrid outcome prediction model for severe traumatic brain injury. Journal of Neurotrauma, 24(1), 136-146.
```

How can I show all authors in the Bibliography section? Seems to be a limit to the number of authors shown but can't find where to set it.

Comment: FWIW, this is standard APA citation style formatting. See http://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2009/08/formatting-apa-references-with-more-than-seven-authors.html. You might get the desired output with a different style.